# Creating registry keys on 32bit systems in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to create different keys in Windows registry (32bit based) but my object "registryKey" is always null for unknown reason.

```
RegistryKey registryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);
using (registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\MyProgram"))
{
     if (registryKey != null)
     {
          registryKey.SetValue("AnyKey", "AnyValue", RegistryValueKind.String);
     }
     else
     {
          Console.Write("object is null ..");
     }
}
```

Comment: "my current code / object always returns null "  -- what return?  I don't see you returning anything anywhere.  Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: It's not returning in that way - my object "registryKey" is just always null.

Comment: You do realize that this line -- `RegistryKey registryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);` assigns a value to `registryKey`, and then you do nothing with that value and overwrite it on the next line with `using (registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\MyProgram"))`.  But that's not the problem here.  Just wanted to point out that your first line is not doing anything useful.

Comment: Well, does "Software\MyProgram" exist in the HKCU branch of the registry? And most importantly, did you spend a little time reading the [MSDN documentation for RegistryKey.OpenSubKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx)? (Also, pay attention to the comment of rory.ap above me...)

Comment: Thanks. It's working now.